# GREP truncates output

Tags: command-line, grep

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I have this output generated by [`laravel`](https://laravel.com/):

```
POST       ajax/work/{id}/origin/{oid}/ .. generated::mpknXZVi6380sw5G › WorkController@createWork
POST       work/{id}/import-works ........ generated::B71o4dgZVUTBXJXw › WorkController@importWorks
```

If I execute `grep "POST"` on the output, it truncated like this:

```
POST       ajax/work/{id}/origin/{oid}/ .. generated::mpknXZVi6380sw…
POST       work/{id}/import-works ........ generated::B71o4dgZVUTBXJ…
```

So what's the right procedure to get the full output?

Comment: This is non-standard behaviour. What OS and version? Is it really `grep` that truncates the lines (try `lavarelcommand | grep POST > testfile` and examine the testfile)?

Comment: @LjmDullaart the OS is "Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS" and the textfile is the same, it's truncated even there

Comment: Hm. What about `laravelcommand > testfile ; grep POST testfile` ?  Does that too truncate? And are the full lines in the `testfile`?

Comment: I think it's more likely that the laravel command itself is modifying its output based on whether it is writing to a pipe versus a tty

Comment: @steeldriver That's why I added the second test. On the other hand `laravelcommand | cat` should also be sufficient as test.

Comment: Can you upload input file with that data? Which grep version do you use?

Comment: Is your `grep` command aliased to something, or overloaded by a shell function? Check with `type -a grep`.